# Значение слова "позаботиться"

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, стилистика, семантика, интонация

Меняется ли значение слова **позаботиться** в этом примере? Есть ли здесь ирония?

*Бандиты ограбили квартиру, замечают убегающего свидетеля, и один бандит говорит остальным: «Я о нём позабочусь» — и бежит за ним.*

Comment: Здесь более подходящее значение: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/позаботиться

Comment: @oleedd спасибо за помощь, но насчет вики я не думаю, что это как-то отвечает на вопрос и вообще конструктивно помогает. Вы списываете на семантику то, что совершенно не вяжется с этимологией слова. Забота от зоб - корм/кормить. То есть выхаживать кого-то, помогать, а убийство как бы совсем не связано с заботой. Значение значением, но нарушение этимологии расширением семантического допуска неуместно. То есть вы сейчас с помощью викисловаря взяли и ввели убийство на уровень заботы. Так и разрушается структура языка.

Comment: @άνθρωπος Нет, там "выполнить". Здесь "позабочусь" подразумевает выполнение задания. В других случаях могут вырубить, закрыть, связать.

Comment: @oleedd это так не работает, есть этимологический смысл слова воспринимаемый интуитивно, любая семантика - это сленг. Сленг тоже имеет контекст. Здесь позаботиться это сленг и сарказм - циничное отношение к понятию "забота", он заботиться не о другом, а о себе, навредив другому. Вы же все сводите до лукавого: а давайте смысл этого слова будет внезапно другой. Так не бывает, точнее бывает, но не стоит так делать от слова совсем. Не все хорошо, что написано на вики. У слова позаботиться есть моральный статус - оказание помощи, а если его нет, то все дозволено. Может без Достоевского?

Comment: @άνθρωπος Здесь чётко значение "займусь", оно современное (но не сленговое), в этом значении слово часто употребляется (фильмы, сериалы). А то, что на вики, близко.

Comment: @oleedd вы понимаете разницу между семантикой и этимологией?

Comment: @άνθρωπος Вопрос-то о семантике. Этимологию обсуждать не буду.

Comment: @oleedd - русский язык не семантичен, по крайней мере пока. И мне бы хотелось, чтобы так оно и оставалось. А то что у викикриэйтеров есть проблемы с пониманием логики чужого языка - это не мои проблемы.

Comment: @άνθρωπος Люди не учитывают этимологию, когда используют слова, поэтому новые значения могут существенно отличаться от старых. Уверен, что над словарём работают русскоязычные.

Comment: @oleedd дело не в отличии, а в логической структуре языка. Вы можете назвать арбузом селёдку - но это будет другой язык, новорусский или неороссийский, но не русский. Русский язык практический не семантичен, потому что в русском языке нет обозначающей единицы - слова. Слово в русском уже смысловая фраза или около того, а смысл привязан к этимологии или идиоматике, а не к семантике. Русскоязычные или нет, насилие над языком - без меня, я и так не грамотный. Про людей. Люди, извините, это как раз те, кто создают этимологию, а не учитывают ея - СУБЪЕКТЫ. Так что говорите за себя, а не за людей.

Comment: @oleedd люди - очень древнее слово, его варианты были во многих языка. И то как вы используете это слово отражает всю спутанность вашей мысли, при этом вы можете быть весьма грамотны, но грамотность - это еще не все, извините.

Comment: @άνθρωπος Ой, он часто от неё так далеко уходит, что связь не улавливается. А субъекты не люди?

Comment: @oleedd Субъекты - это не люди, это термин весьма специфический из психологии и психоанализа. Субъект - это вид психики человека(или её часть), которая завязана на бессознательное. То есть Субъект связан с индивидом и атомарным состоянием. Субъекты быть людьми никак не могут, потому что люди, это имеющие общее представление о мире - мире ценностей. Представление субъекта индивидуально, из n-субъектов не соберешь людей никак, это как детальки лего которые друг к другу не подходят и вообще не детальки а набор совершенно несочетающихся предметов. А люди - это сочетающееся и дополняющее.

Comment: Субъект противопоставлен объективной реальности. Объективная реальность - это реальность оцененная по определенному внешнему принципу, например - цвет штанов или статус на вики. А ценностный мир людей вообще особнячком, потому что ценности - это то, что нельзя оценить, такой каламбур. В общем это вообще не то, уж поверьте)

Comment: А, ну да, и субъект как раз полагается на знаковую семантическую систему сформированную на базе (естественного) языка. Проблема в том, что вся эта семантика нужна для "программирование" субъекта на определенные реактивные действия, то есть обозначающее знаковое слово триггерит подсознание и у субъекта рождается мотивационный импульс активности. Как-то так, а про людей, можете тоже на вики почитать - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_vocabulary . Если и читаете вики, то читайте хотя бы английскую, все-таки их проект

Comment: @άνθρωπος Откройте толковые словари, субъект — это человек (не только).

Comment: @oleedd ой ну хоть вот почитайте, пожалуйста, https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/brokgauz/20358 - там слово человек по-моему даже не встречается несмотря на пару страниц текста.

Comment: @άνθρωπος Слушайте, это слово не только термин философии, логики, психологии, у него есть и обычные значения (этот сайт как раз о таких).

Comment: @oleedd, я видел значение этого слова, но не думаю, что в моем примере оно подпадает под это значение.

Comment: @plotnikov.tosha2016 Почему? *Выполню то, что следует [разберусь с ним].*

Answer (score 1):

Да, хотя это, конечно, звучит как сарказм. Потому что он его убьет, а не позаботится). По-английски так сказать нельзя, потому что там слова указывают на конкретное действие, и заботиться - помогать, и если не уточнять, то не ясно что имеется ввиду. То есть нужно добавить либо объяснение: я помогу ему умереть, или создать сленг словечко.

В русском логика допускает додумывание слова, потому что, я сейчас скажу странную вещь, но слова в русском это не слова как семантические единицы, это уже полноценные фразы, каждое слово - это наборная почти фраза или полноценная фраза состоящая из префиксов, суффиксов и других элементов изменяющих значение начального слова часто вплоть до противоположного. Конечно, важно учитывать и контекст. В этом контексте "позабочусь" будет означать действие, противоположное заботе.

Ну и я к тому, что включайте логику русского языка, не думайте по-английский, хотя это довольно сложно, потому что культурного контента с запада сейчас очень много и люди начинают(или пытаются) говорить/слышать по-русски через логику английского языка.

И еще момент. Вот ты пишешь: бандиты ограбили квартиру и замечают свидетеля... Это идет в разрез с логикой западного человека. Бандит - это грабитель да, но грабеж - это воровство при свидетелях с применением силы. То есть ты уже воспринимаешь этих людей как бандитов, хотя в начальный момент твоего рассуждения они, по логике западного человека, еще пока воры или хотя бы не грабят. А вот когда они замечают свидетеля они становятся бандитами. Но у русского человека нет  "линейной(формальной)" логической структуры в голове, потому что нет и не всегда необходимо расставлять слова на свои места, слово как смысловая фраза не имеет начала и конца, а воспринимается целиком. То есть у тебя не вызывает диссонанса, что ты сделал вывод до обозначения его в конце, то есть предвосхитил вывод. А для логики западного человека это будет прямо бессвязное что-то. Их сознание может зацепится за терминологию и очередность ее появления. Короче, ты можешь одной такой фразой сломать им весь мозг.